# Is practice effect on matrix-based IQ tests largely attributable to question feedback?

Tags: iq

I took the TRI-52, which is strongly correlated with [other cognitive ability tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qniRV.png). When I first took it, I was tired, my mind was foggy, and my ADD was acting up -- I got a score of 116. The following day, I took it while well rested & with improved concentration, and got a score of 125. I did not receive any feedback on any of the questions, so I've no idea which questions I got right or wrong; this might mitigate the impacts of the practice effect. Which is a more accurate representation of my score? My first attempt, even though I took it in suboptimal conditions, or my second attempt, which might be susceptible to practice effect?

Comment: Those scores are probably within the margin of error, which means they are effectively the same.

Comment: What do those scores mean, in terms of intellectual ability?

Comment: Not much, honestly. IQ tests are only really useful in looking at populations and in diagnosing serious disability. In the middle they aren't very predictive for individuals.

Comment: Isn't the margin of error between exams supposed to be ~5, not ~9?

Comment: I'll repeat myself: "IQ tests are only really useful in looking at populations and in diagnosing serious disability. In the middle they aren't very predictive for individuals." There isn't a practical meaning of the difference between the scores. It doesn't matter what the specific test-retest reliability is for a given test, that doesn't tell you anything except about the test itself.